# MQ Queue manager alias

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

In our application we are maintaining queue manager names in the configuration file which are stored in database. At any time, only one queue manager name can be specified in the configuration file.

To support application fail over, it is required to connect to another queue manager with a different name.

It makes no sense to duplicate all configuration files due to different queue manager name. Is there any way at MQ level (`alias` may be) to refer with the same queue manager in the configuration file, but if the DR location is active it should connect to new queue manager.

Comment: Use a blank QM name or a star.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks for your answer. How does then application know which queue manager to connects to?

Comment: It connects to the queue manager that is listening on the ip and port provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting IBM MQ queue using F5 virtual ip and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679018/connecting-ibm-mq-queue-using-f5-virtual-ip-and-c)

Comment: Also take a look at these two "[How to create a qmgr alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438479/how-to-create-a-qmgr-alias/42441330#42441330)" and "[JMSWMQ2020: Failed to connect to queue manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331726/jmswmq2020-failed-to-connect-to-queue-manager/48332035#48332035)"

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As JoshMc said, use a blank or star for the queue manager name.  After the connection, the application can use the getName method to retrieve the name of the queue manager.

```
MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(" ", mqht);
System.out.println("QMgr="+qMgr.getName());
```

Note: mqht is a Hashtable with the connection parameters.